# Concentrar todo um array em uma variável que imprima em DOMPDF

Tags: php, arraylist

li algumas postagens daqui, mas nada que me desse um norte. Tenho um php que imprimi em PDF, com duas querys que consultam o Banco de dados, uma tabela possui uma foreing Key da outra. Ou seja, para uma chave eu tenho várias linhas numa outra tabela. 
Fiz duas Querys porque a tabela SOFTWARE, também tem uma linha com o nome de NAME e eu não posso alterar esse nome.

```
$query = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT h.NAME, h.IPSRC, h.PATRIMONIO, h.PRIVILEGIO, n.MACADDR, r.NOME_RESPONSAVEL, r.MAT FROM hardware as h, softwares as s, networks as n, responsavel as r WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID AND h.IPSRC = '{$ip}' AND h.ID = n.HARDWARE_ID AND r.ID = h.ID_RESP LIMIT 1");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $mat = $aux["MAT"];
            $nome_resp = $aux["NOME_RESPONSAVEL"];
            $host =  $aux["NAME"];
            $numpat =  $aux["PATRIMONIO"];
            $privilegio = $aux["PRIVILEGIO"];
            $mac = $aux["MACADDR"];
            }

$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT s.NAME FROM hardware as h, softwares as s WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID AND h.IPSRC = '{$ip}' ORDER BY s.NAME");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 

                $soft = $aux["NAME"];
            }

        //referenciar o DomPDF com namespace
        use Dompdf\Dompdf;

        // include autoloader
        require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

        //Criando a Instancia
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

        // Carrega seu HTML
        $dompdf->load_html('

        <BR><BR><center><b>TERMO DE COMPROMISSO PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇO</b></center><BR><BR>

            <div id="lista" style="text-align: justify;">Pelo presente documento, eu, Matrícula: '.$mat.', '.$nome_resp.', perante a EMPRESA, na qualidade de  Prestador de serviço, responsabilizo-me pelo uso da Estação de trabalho '.$numpat.' com as seguintes configurações:</justify><BR><BR>
            <b>II – Programas:</b><BR>
            a) Programas instalados: '.$soft.' <BR>


        ');
```

Na variável $soft, eu tenho uma lista de programas permitidos pela empresa para serem usados, mas o DOMPDF só lista o último programas da lista, por isso pensei em um array.

Me deem uma força aí galera!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar `array`, uma `string` dá conta. Quando você busca o valor para `$soft` a cada iteração você está sobrescrevendo o valor obtido na iteração anterior.

Eu modifiquei a linha onde pega o valor para `$soft`, ao invés de sobrescrever eu usei o operado `.=` para concatenar o valor já existente em `$soft` com o valor obtido na iteração.

```
$query = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT h.NAME, h.IPSRC, h.PATRIMONIO, h.PRIVILEGIO, n.MACADDR, r.NOME_RESPONSAVEL, r.MAT FROM hardware as h, softwares as s, networks as n, responsavel as r WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID AND h.IPSRC = '{$ip}' AND h.ID = n.HARDWARE_ID AND r.ID = h.ID_RESP LIMIT 1");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $mat = $aux["MAT"];
            $nome_resp = $aux["NOME_RESPONSAVEL"];
            $host =  $aux["NAME"];
            $numpat =  $aux["PATRIMONIO"];
            $privilegio = $aux["PRIVILEGIO"];
            $mac = $aux["MACADDR"];
            }

$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT s.NAME FROM hardware as h, softwares as s WHERE h.ID = s.HARDWARE_ID AND h.IPSRC = '{$ip}' ORDER BY s.NAME");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 

                // A cada iteração você concatena o valor anterior com o atual
                $soft .= ($aux["NAME"] . '<BR>');
            }

        //referenciar o DomPDF com namespace
        use Dompdf\Dompdf;

        // include autoloader
        require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

        //Criando a Instancia
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

        // Carrega seu HTML
        $dompdf->load_html('

        <BR><BR><center><b>TERMO DE COMPROMISSO PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇO</b></center><BR><BR>

            <div id="lista" style="text-align: justify;">Pelo presente documento, eu, Matrícula: '.$mat.', '.$nome_resp.', perante a EMPRESA, na qualidade de  Prestador de serviço, responsabilizo-me pelo uso da Estação de trabalho '.$numpat.' com as seguintes configurações:</justify><BR><BR>
            <b>II – Programas:</b><BR>
            a) Programas instalados: '.$soft.' <BR>


        ');
```

Comment: Perfeito Augusto!!! Perfeito